# If $y_n=\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2}x_n)$, how do I express $y_{n+1}$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

If $y_n=\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2}x_n)$, how do you express the $y_{n+1}$

I attempt to transform $\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2}x_n)$ into $\frac{1}{2} ({1-\cos(\pi x_n))}$ by using double-angle formula, but I have no idea what to do from this. Any advice will be appericiated.

$$x_{n+1} =  
\begin{cases}
      2x_n & 0<x_n< 1/2\\
2(1-x_n) & 1/2\leq x_n\leq 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Unless there's a specific definition for $x_n$, I don't really see any value in doing anything other than replacing $n$ with $n+1$ in the definition for the sequence $y_{n+1}$. Seems like there's some context we're missing here? Is there, for example, a specific way in which you want to express it? What is $x_n$?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer sorry, I forgot to add the specific definition for $x_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0<x_n <1/2$ then $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x_{n+1})=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}2x_n)= \sin( \pi x_n).$.

If $ 1/2 \le x_n \le 1$, then $x_{n+1}=2(1-x_n)$. Now use the addition theorem for $\sin$ to get again

$\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x_{n+1})=\sin( \pi x_n).$

Hence: $y_{n+1}=\sin^2( \pi x_n).$